# How to make LED flash once every 5 seconds using using 555 timer?

Tags: led

I know this is not new but i really can't find a circuit that makes an led flash once every 5 secs. I hope somebody can help me out.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/51547/simple-energy-efficient-circuit-to-make-single-ir-led-blink

Comment: If you *really* want to use a 555, you'll probably want to start with a [calculator to find the capacitor/resistor values you need](http://www.ohmslawcalculator.com/555-astable-calculator). That particular circuit gives a minimum of 50% duty cycle. If you want a short flash every 5 seconds, then you could design it for a high duty cycle, and use a transistor to drive the LED *and* invert the signal coming from the 555. It's almost certainly easier and cheaper to do this with a tiny microcontroller than a 555 though.

Comment: only one 20mA LED? from what V?

Answer (score 1):

An LM3909 is an 8 pin IC designed for exactly that, flashing LEDs. It operates on 1v to 5v and is very conservative on power usage. The datasheets are easy to find online.

Comment: i need it to operate on 12v for my car.

Comment: You can consider using an LDO.  The MAQ5280 is an automotive grade LDO that may be worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

Search for '555 LED flasher circuit' and go to Images.  Tons of schematics.  Plus, the 555 datasheet has many application circuits included.

https://images.search.yahoo.com/search/images;_ylt=AwrBT9aU78JZVM0AuihXNyoA;_ylu=X3oDMTE0NzBpZW00BGNvbG8DYmYxBHBvcwMxBHZ0aWQDVUkyQzNfMQRzZWMDcGl2cw--?p=555+led+flasher+circuit&fr2=piv-web